# DCCfit speed up formula

Tags: volatility, risk-management

I am estimating the covariance matrix by using GARCH DCC model with function dccfit from package rmgarch. My code is something like:

- library(rugarch)
- library(rmgarch)

> ```
>    uspec.n = multispec(replicate(dim(log_cls)[2], ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(1,1)))))
>     dcc.11mn = dccspec(uspec.n, dccOrder = c(1, 1), distribution = 'mvnorm')
>     dccfit(dcc.11mn, returns,fit.control = list(eval.se = FALSE),solver =c("hybrid","solnp"))
> ```

I have 1000 historical data for 200 assets, so you can image the estimation is rather slow. Does anyone have a suggestion how to speed up the code, since I will have to do a rolling estimation for almost 100 times? Is there a package in R which is faster for this model? Or some processor speed up trick?

Thank you!